# Array on python function

Tags: python, arrays

Please help. It's really children's question but I'm at a loss. Why I can't to return array?

There is my script :

```
groups=[]

host_groups_list = '/usr/local/host_groups.list'

def read_file(file_path):
        open_file = open(host_groups_list, "r+")
        list=[]
        for i in open_file:
                list.append(str(i.replace("\n", "")))
        print list
        return list

goups = read_file(host_groups_list)
print groups
```

Output :

```
['hostgroup1', 'hostgroup2']
[]
```

Comment: 1. You didn't close that file after you open it. 2. A typo and use `list` as variable name as Mike said. 3. `list.append(str(i.replace("\n", "")))`, `str()` is useless here. 4. I think you mean `open_file = open(file_path, "r+")` instead of `open_file = open(host_groups_list, "r+")`. 5. `groups = with open(''/usr/local/host_groups.list'') as f: [i.strip() for i in f]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spelling is important:

```
goups = read_file(host_groups_list)
print groups
```

Note the missing `r` in `goups`.

You don't need the `groups=[]` in the beginning. Delete it and Python will give a name error for your print statement.

Better don't use `list` as a name for your variables because it shadows a built-in.

Comment: @JustMe: use editor with auto-completion (I personally recommend Sublime Text 2) to avoid mistakes like this in future. And, don't create unneeded globals.